# CiviEvent Scheduled Reminder using SMS

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders, sms

I have to following use case:

I need to send SMSes to the guardians / parents of the event participants when the participants did not attend/no-show 15 minutes after the event starts.

I am incline to write a scheduled job to scan the civicrm status and then send out the SMS via the CiviCRM REST APIs.

Would this be the correct approach or there is already building blocks that are out-of-the-box that I can leverage on to implement the use case.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the two extensions CiviRules and SMS API.

We are using those two in combinations, to send a sms whenever certain triggers and conditions are met.